# how to create crud on google cloud storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I'm developing an app that use google cloud service, i mounted a local develop server, today i developed the create of crud, down the code:

```
    Entity.Builder entRestaurante = Entity.newBuilder();
    entRestaurante.setKey(makeKey());
    entRestaurante.addProperty(makeProperty(ID, makeValue(restaurante.getId())));
    entRestaurante.addProperty(makeProperty(CAMPUS, makeValue(restaurante.getId())));
    entRestaurante.addProperty(makeProperty(NOME, makeValue(restaurante.getId())));
    entRestaurante.addProperty(makeProperty(INICIO_HORARIO, makeValue(restaurante.getInicioHorario())));
    entRestaurante.addProperty(makeProperty(FIM_HORARIO, makeValue(restaurante.getFimHorario())));

    Mutation.Builder mutation = Mutation.newBuilder();
    mutation.add(entRestaurante);

    CommitRequest.newBuilder()
            .setMutation(mutation)
            .setMode(CommitRequest.Mode.NON_TRANSACTIONAL)
            .build();
```

This is working fine i think, searching o object *Mutation* i saw he has methods to do the rest of crud that i need addDelete, addUpdate:

**1- How can i use this guys? Could someone show me?**

I tryied this to do the read of crud:

```
public List<Restaurante> obtem(final Restaurante filtro) {
    List<Restaurante> listaRetorno = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Filter> filtros = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        filtros.add(makeFilter(
                ID, PropertyFilter.Operator.EQUAL, makeValue(filtro.getId())).build());

        filtros.add(makeFilter(
                CAMPUS, PropertyFilter.Operator.EQUAL, makeValue(filtro.getCampus())).build());

        filtros.add(makeFilter(
                NOME, PropertyFilter.Operator.EQUAL, makeValue(filtro.getNome())).build());

        filtros.add(makeFilter(
                FIM_HORARIO, PropertyFilter.Operator.EQUAL, makeValue(filtro.getFimHorario())).build());

        filtros.add(makeFilter(
                INICIO_HORARIO, PropertyFilter.Operator.EQUAL, makeValue(filtro.getInicioHorario())).build());

        Filter enconteIgual = makeFilter(filtros).build();

        Query.Builder query = Query.newBuilder();
        query.addKindBuilder().setName(DATA_SET_NAME);
        query.setFilter(enconteIgual)
                .setLimit(1)
                .build();

        RunQueryRequest request = RunQueryRequest.newBuilder().setQuery(query).build();
        RunQueryResponse response = datastore.runQuery(request);

        for (EntityResult result : response.getBatch().getEntityResultList()) { //Here problem when try to read the values 
            Map<String, Value> props = getPropertyMap(result.getEntity());
            String id = getString(props.get(ID));
            String campus = getString(props.get(CAMPUS));
            String nome = getString(props.get(NOME));
            Date inicioHorario = obtenhaData(getString(props.get(INICIO_HORARIO)));
            Date fimHorario = obtenhaData(getString(props.get(FIM_HORARIO)));

            listaRetorno.add(new Restaurante(
                    id,
                    campus,
                    nome,
                    inicioHorario,
                    fimHorario));
        }

        if (response.getBatch().getMoreResults() == QueryResultBatch.MoreResultsType.NOT_FINISHED) {
            ByteString endCursor = response.getBatch().getEndCursor();
            query.setStartCursor(endCursor);
        }

        return listaRetorno;

    } catch (DatastoreException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RestauranteRepositoryImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

But the response on the *response.getBatch().getEntityResultList()* is an exception MORE_RESULTS_AFTER_LIMIT

**2- Does anyone know what is this response? Where is the elements that satisfy the 'select'?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use the `addUpdate()`, `addUpsert()`, `addDelete()`, `addInsert()`, or `addInsertAutoId()` methods on `Mutation.Builder` to add mutations. You can find some examples of how to use these methods in the [Cloud Datastore documentation on working with entities](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Working_with_entities).
2. Your code is doing the right thing here. The results from the query are found by calling `getEntity()` on the items in `RunQueryResponse.getBatch().getEntityResultList()`. As for `MORE_RESULTS_AFTER_LIMIT`, this may currently be returned even if there are no additional results ([issue tracker](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/48)). As a workaround, you can continue your query until you receive a batch with zero results.

Comment: i can't test it now but i think that will solve my problem thanks a lot ( if in fact it solve i will upvote your sugestion )